# JTable multiselect loses selection when table data changes

Tags: java, swing, jtable

A `JTable` displays data from an array of objects. Object data changes in the background and the table is updated. When rows are selected and the table data changes the row selections are lost. It is difficult for the user to select rows for an action when the selections are frequently lost.

Is there a way to stop the deselection?

Comment: What events are you using to update the table? Have considered pausing updates while there are selected rows? What happens if te row tat I selected is updated/changes?

Comment: There are calls to methods in the table model that invokeLater a call to fireTableDataChanged. Is there a way to detect that rows are selected?

Comment: Yes, BUT, what happens if a row is deleted from the model which was selected?  The only information you really have is the index.  Also, you shouldn't be doing anything with the selection model from within the `TableModel`

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726896/table-model-update-firetabledatachanged-disrupts-table-selection)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found using the debugger. The row selection is being cleared during the call to fireTableDataChanged, which I was using to apply the updates in the table.

Apparently that method redraws the table and the selection may not be valid (as suggested by the MadProgrammer comment above). I will still be needing that feature when objects (rows) are be added or removed.

So what I must do is find a way to notify the table model to make updates to without clearing the selection. I have chosen for now to use fireTableRowsUpdated when updates are to be applied that do not require restructuring the table and fireTableDataChanged otherwise.